# How to represent timeline events in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, nodes, timeline

I need to create a graph database with events that happenedd during a period of time. Those events have happened at a particular moment in time and some of them are cause or effect of some actors doing some actions. The actors graph database is already created but I don't have a clear idea of how to represent the timeline of events in relation to those actors.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432916/time-based-data-in-neo4j.

Comment: see http://gist.neo4j.org/?github-kbastani/gists//meta/TimeScaleEventMetaModel.adoc

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look to this blog :
http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/02/modeling-multilevel-index-in-neoj4.html

it shows one of the way to represent time in graph and how to index it.
When it comes to cause/effect representation could you explain more clearly your case.
(With an example maybe ?)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GraphAware TimeTree module which is based on the multilevel index linked to by @Morendo
The blog post: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html

And the docs: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree

Disclaimer: I work for GraphAware